# jQuery Find element from data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems finding and setting the value of an element based on data set with jQuery.

The data is set like this:

```
$(this).data('scanner', {type: 'input', id: index});
```

And then I'm trying to set the value of the element like this:

```
$('[data-type="input"][data-id="0"]').val(string);
```

But nothing is set... the console doesn't throw any errors either.

Comment: that is because you are using attribute selector for data value - you can't do that

Comment: You need to use them as attribute values if you want to use them in selectors

Comment: `$(this).attr({'data-type': 'input', 'data-id': index});`

Comment: If I wanted to find by using data properly would it be `$('data(scanner.type=='input',scanner.id==0)');` ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("some_selector").filter(function(){
    var scannerData = $(this).data('scanner');
    return scannerData 
           && scannerData.type === "input" 
           && scannerData.id === 1;
}).val("some string");
```

Here's an example:

```js
$("#div1").data('scanner',{type: 'input', id: 1});

$('div').filter(function(){
  var scannerData = $(this).data('scanner');
  return scannerData && scannerData.type === "input" && scannerData.id === 1;
}).text("Updated");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">Div1 (has data)</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
```

Comment: If I wanted to find by using data properly would it be `$('data(scanner.type=='input',scanner.id==0)');` ?

Comment: @ChrisByatt Ive updated the answer and added an example - hopefully will help.

Comment: Didn't saw your answer, removed duplicate

Comment: @Tushar thanks for the code review. Lazy answer by me - you made it better!

Comment: @Jamiec Welcome :). Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33105496/using-jquery-ui-data-selector#33105496